# I have made a program in C++ to separate words from a line by spacebar and display those words as an array. What's wrong in my code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, codeblocks

Please help me to find a bug in this program.It separates a line into words by spacebar. And display as a list.
If the first char of a word is in lower case, it is converted to uppercase.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char line[30]="Hi there buddy",List[10][20];
    unsigned int i=0,List_pos=0,no;
    int first=0,last;

    while(i!=sizeof(line)+1)
    {
        if(line[i]==' ' or i==sizeof(line))
        {
            last=i;
            no=0;
            for(int j=first;j<last;++j)
            {
                if(no==0)
                    List[List_pos][no]=toupper(line[j]);
                else
                    List[List_pos][no]=line[j];
                ++no;
            }
            ++List_pos;
            first=last+1;
        }
    ++i;
    }

    for(unsigned int a=0;a<List_pos;++a)
        cout<<"\nList["<<a+1<<"]="<<List[a];

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
List[1]=Hi    
List[2]=There    
List[3]=Buddy
```

Actual Output:

```
List[1]=Hi    
List[2]=ThereiXŚm    
List[3]=Buddy
```

Comment: you need to store `'\0'` at the end of each string.

Comment: Unrelated, `while(i!=sizeof(line)+1)` is a recipe for disaster. accessing `line[i]` when `i` equals `sizeof(line)` (allowed by your condition due to the `+1`) invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Hersh In general the code is wrong.At lleast it does not work correct;y when there are several blanks between words.

Comment: @Hersh Take into account that the header <string> is redundant in your program. Neither declaration from the header is used in your program.

Comment: @Hersh *What's wrong in my code?*  -- Not using `std::string`, not using `std::vector`, and not using `std::istringstream`.  If you used those, the length of the program is 4 lines.

Comment: [As demonstrated by this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d848850da78ed280).  The bulk of the program is 4 or 5 lines, with the other lines used as variable declaration and output.

Comment: I have learnt C++ up to classes. I am trying to make my own algorithms. I am a newbie,if you have any advice, I would like to hear from you.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a string, as you already included it. And 'List is not really necessary in this situation. Try making a single for loop where you separate your line into words, in my opinion when you work with arrays you should use for loops. In your for loop, as you go through the line, you could just add a if statement which determines whether you're at the end of a word or not. I think the problem in your code is the multiple loops but I am not sure of it.

I provide you a code which works. Just adapt it to your display requirements and you will be fine

````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line = "Hi there buddy";

    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
        if (line[i] == ' ') {
            line[i + 1] = toupper(line[i+1]);
            cout<<'\n';
        } else {
            cout<<line[i];
        }

    }

    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: You forgot to include <iostream>. The code does not compile. You are using ````using namespace std;````. The program does not produce the expected result. What would happen, if the input string would be ````"Hi there buddy "````, with a space at the end? But otherwise very good: You got 2 upvotes!

Comment: We could modify the if statement so it determines whether we are at the end of the string or not. The code I provided is extremely simple, took me 10 minutes to finish. I am aware it has a LOT of weaknesses but the goal was only to fix the output problem. But it would be interesting to modify it, specially if it is some kind of homework (a program without any possible bug is often better graded :D ).

Comment: When we input line from the user, it only shows first word. What should we do? By thanks for correcting me. I have learnt upto classes and OOP. Trying to make algorithms. If you have any advice please share with me.

Comment: You mean you modified it so it takes a user input? Could you please send the code then?

Answer (score 1):

Challenged by the comment from PaulMcKenzie, I implemented a C++ solution with 3 statements:

1. Define a `std::string`, with the words to work on
2. Define a `std::regex` that finds words only. Whitespaces and other delimiters are ignored
3. Use the `std::transform` to transform the input string into output lines

`std::transform` has 4 parameters.

1. With what the transformation should begin. In this case, we use the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. This will look for the regex (so, for the word) and return the first word. That's the begin.
2. With what the transformation should end. We use the empty `std::sregex_token_iterator`. That means: Do until all matches (all words) have been read.
3. The destination. For this we will use the `std::ostream_iterator`. This will send all transformed results (what the lambda returns) to the given output stream (in our case `std::cout`). And it will add a delimiter, here a newline ("\n").
4. The transormation function. Implemented as lambda. Here we get the word from the `std::sregex_token_iterator` and transform it into a new word according to what we want. So, a word with a capitalized first letter. We add a little bit text for the output line as wished by the OP.

Please check:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    // 1. This is the string to convert
    std::string line("Hi there buddy");

    // 2. We want to search for complete words
    std::regex word("(\\w+)");

    // 3. Transform the input string to output lines
    std::transform(
        std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), word, 1),
        std::sregex_token_iterator(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
        [i = 1](std::string w) mutable {                               
            return std::string("List[") + std::to_string(i++) + "]=" + static_cast<char>(::toupper(w[0])) + &w[1];
        }
    );
    return 0;
}
```

This will give us the following output:

```
List[1]=Hi
List[2]=There
List[3]=Buddy
```

Please get a feeling for the capabilities of C++

Comment: For statement count, you need to count the statements in lambda too... Also cramming multiple statements into one line isn't something I would encourage (especially not implicitly by writing example code which does so).

Comment: @hyde: Thank you: I will update the code to make it more readable, I can also put the counter per reference in the capture. But it is just an example. I hope that it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for your next problem (when the user inputs a sentence only the first word it displayed). When you input a "space", the cin just thinks you are done. You need to use the getLine() to get the whole sentence.

```
getline(cin, line);
```

Instead of

```
cin>>line;
```